# How to JUnit test for any output in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'd like to test the two methods below, but because its based on random output my go-to `assertEquals()` won't work.

I just want to test to ensure the methods are producing some kind of output.  Any ideas?

Novice programmer, appreciate the help.

```
    public void compRandomChoice() {
    double choice = (Math.random() * 100 / 100);

    if (choice > 0 && choice <= 0.34) {
        computer.setChoice(HandThrow.ROCK);
    } else if (choice > 0.34 && choice <= 0.67) {
        computer.setChoice(HandThrow.PAPER);
    } else {
        computer.setChoice(HandThrow.SCISSORS);
    }
}


    public String gameWinner() {
    String gameResult;

    if (human.getChoice() == computer.getChoice()) {
        gameResult = "ITS A TIE!";
    } else if (human.getChoice() == HandThrow.ROCK
            && computer.getChoice() == HandThrow.SCISSORS
            || human.getChoice() == HandThrow.PAPER
            && computer.getChoice() == HandThrow.ROCK
            || human.getChoice() == HandThrow.SCISSORS
            && computer.getChoice() == HandThrow.PAPER) {
        gameResult = "CONGRATS, YOU WIN!";
    } else {
        gameResult = "COMPUTER WINS!";
    }
    return gameResult;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest changing `compRandomChoice()`  function  as follows

```
public void compRandomChoice(double rand_no) {
    double choice = (rand_no * 100 / 100);

    if (choice > 0 && choice <= 0.34) {
        computer.setChoice(HandThrow.ROCK);
    } else if (choice > 0.34 && choice <= 0.67) {
        computer.setChoice(HandThrow.PAPER);
    } else {
        computer.setChoice(HandThrow.SCISSORS);
    }
}
```

Then in your program, you can call it as `compRandomChoice(Math.random())` Now in your Unit Tests,
you can hard-code the input, e.g. `compRandomChoice(0.5)` and assert that the result is as expected.

Similarly, change `public String gameWinner()` as `public String gameWinner(String  human_choice, String computer_choice)`

```
 public String gameWinner(String human_choice, String computer_choice) {
    String gameResult;

    if (human_choice == computer_choice) {
        gameResult = "ITS A TIE!";
    .......
```

In your code, you can call the function as `gameWinner(human.getChoice(), computer.getChoice())`. In your Unit Tests, you can hard code the input (using an approach similar to used for previous function) and assert that you get expected result based on the parameter you are passing.

Comment: This looks like the best route given the choices, however it would require me to do some extensive restructuring of my code based around the MVC concept, so for now I'm using an assertNotNull to get the job done in a pinch.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are discovering is that you want to test (assert) that your code behaves correctly given certain inputs, but that you can not easily control the inputs in question as your code is written. Congratulations! You have discovered (one of) the virtues of test-driven development.

The solution is to re-structure your code in a way that makes it easier to test the properties you care about.

What property do you care about for the `compRandomChoice` function? Perhaps that it produces an output that is evenly distributed across the three choices. To do that, you might imagine writing a short test that iterates over many calls to `compRandomChoice` and does some simple analysis (and the Law of Large Numbers) to show that you get each choice about a third of the time.

How about for the `gameWinner` function? There you want to try different combinations of inputs and verify that the correct winner is determined. The inputs to the algorithm are the choices made by the computer and the human. So to test it, you must be able to manufacture human and computer choices and provide them to the algorithm. This would typically be done by using dependency injection...that is providing the objects that your algorithm depends on in the constructor or as a parameter instead of hard-coding them.

For example, the simplest thing to do would be to pass the choices into the `gameWinner` function and have it return a the winner (e.g., as an enum):

```
enum Result { PLAYER1, PLAYER2, TIE }
/**
 * Determine the game winner.
 * @param player1_choice
 * @param player2_choice
 * @return PLAYER1 .
 */
public Result gameWinner(HandThrow player1_choice, HandThrow player2_choice) {
    if (player1_choice.equals(player2_choice)) { return TIE }
    ...
}
```

Then the tests are easy to write:

```
@Test
public void paperBeatsRock() {
    assertEquals(gameWinner(HandThrow.ROCK, HandThrow.PAPER), PLAYER2);
}
```

Take a look at [Writing Testable Code](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/); it gives a lot of hints on how to do what you want to do successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I'm going to dig into that.

Answer (score 0):

I would extract getting random into a package private method

```
double getRandomChoice() {
    return (Math.random() * 100 / 100);
}
```

so that in the test I could override it

```
    MyClass mc = new MyClass() {
        @Override
        double getRandomChoice() {
            return 2.0;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

For my needs and time available I found the assertNotNull() test method, and used that.

```
@Test
public void testGameWinner() {
    assertNotNull(testLogic.gameWinner());
```